# Сохранение модели в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Создаю модель, заношу туда атрибуты. Атрибуты забиваются (из отладчика вижу), делаю save, и дальше выдает ошибку:

> CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer ('project0'@'%') does not exist. The SQL statement executed was:

Вот код:

```
        $model = new WorktimeReport('add');
        $model->attributes = $_POST['WorktimeReport'];
        $model->uid=$id;
        $model->gid=$gid;
        $model->rdate=$date;
        if($model->save())
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> General error: 1449 The user
> specified as a definer
> ('project0'@'%') does not exist.

[ОТВЕТ](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_no_such_user)

Comment: Всё, спасибо! разобрался, Вы подтолкнули в какую сторону копать. :)
Оказалось, после загрузки данных с основной базы на тестовую, захватился тригер, который ссылался на другого определителя.